# If I install Windows on another unformatted partition containing some files, would those be deleted?

Tags: windows-8, windows-installation

I have two partitions, one containing **Windows 8** OS (**C:**), and another containing some **non-OS related files** (**D:**). If I choose to install Windows 10 in **D:** drive for dual booting with Windows 8, will the existing files in **D:** drive be deleted?

Comment: If you partition it, no.  If you don't partition, Windows will reformat the drive before installing.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths, Thanks for your answer. Maybe I'll go ahead.

Comment: "unformatted partition containing some files" - unformatted partitions cannot contain files.